# How to compare habitat selection coeficients between groups?

Tags: regression-coefficients, poisson-regression, group-differences

For my thesis I am analysis habitat use of animals. I want to compare habitat selection coeficients between groups, for instance between males and females or between different places. But I do not know of a statistical method that can do this. Does anyone know? Most habitat selection functions are based on clogit. However the one I am using is a poisson regression (https://rdrr.io/github/ctmm-initiative/ctmm/man/RSF.fit.html). I do not really understand but this is what the page says "the output is a log-likelihood is that of the continuous Poisson point process", the class is "ctmm" so I could not direcly use the model in a function I guess. I was already looking around and thought effect modification might also be appropiiate. But ut I don know know enhough statistics to understand it all. So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is some example data of one indiviudal:

low est high

Land_Use.323_12 (1/Land_Use.323_12) -1.531084e+00 -0.4869885 0.5571072

Land_Use.252_12 (1/Land_Use.252_12) -2.072346e+00 -0.9814354 0.1094758

Land_Use.251_12 (1/Land_Use.251_12) -7.794530e+00 -3.6031231 0.5882833

Land_Use.47_12 (1/Land_Use.47_12) -2.249040e+00 -1.1812521 -0.1134644

Land_Use.45_12 (1/Land_Use.45_12) -1.118897e+01 -3.9057274 3.3775193

Land_Use.38_12 (1/Land_Use.38_12) -5.000368e+00 -2.4402699 0.1198286

Land_Use.37_12 (1/Land_Use.37_12) -8.038857e+00 -3.4006010 1.2376549

Land_Use.36_12 (1/Land_Use.36_12) -5.483149e+00 -3.5370652 -1.5909819

Land_Use.35_12 (1/Land_Use.35_12) -7.526605e+00 2.7482648 13.0231348

Land_Use.30_12 (1/Land_Use.30_12) -2.786229e+01 -0.3129170 27.2364516

were a negative number is that the animal selects against a land use. and a positive that it selects for a habitat use. This is the function I used https://rdrr.io/github/ctmm-initiative/ctmm/man/RSF.fit.html

Thanks!